# Because of Child div's height, it is resizing parent div

Tags: css

My search suggestion box is not flowing all the way into the section below rather it is resizing the whole navbar. The search input is in the navigation bar. I want the search suggestions to just flow in the divs below. I have tried all the overflow property values but it is not giving me what I want.

```css
.search-box {
  position: relative;
}
.nav-search {
  width: 260px;
}
.autocom-box {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  width: 260px;
  /* padding: 10px 8px; */
  max-height: 280px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /* opacity: 0; */
  /* pointer-events: none; */
}
.search-box li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  cursor: default;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  /* display: none; */
  overflow: auto;
}
.search-box li:hover {
  background: #efefef;
}
.search-btn {
  height: 38px;
  width: 38px;
  line-height: 38px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: black;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border: none;
  background: none;
}
```

```html
<form class="d-flex ms-auto" action="/" method="post">
  <div class="search-box">
    <input
      class="form-control me-2 nav-search"
      autocomplete="off"
      name="search"
      placeholder="Type to Search..."
    />
    <div class="autocom-box">
      <li>Avengers</li>
      <li>Avengers</li>
      <li>Avengers</li>
      <li>Avengers</li>
    </div>
    <button class="search-btn" type="submit">
      <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

I've tried giving the full navbar max-height but then it tries to keep everything inside of it so it just pushes the search-box so high up it disappears.
And I've also tried `position: absolute;` but even that doesn't work it just messes everything up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `position: absolute;` to the pop-out window (`.autocom-box`) should just about do the trick:

```css
.search-box {
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.nav-search {
  width: 260px;
}
.autocom-box {
  position: absolute; /* This is the change */
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid red;
  color: black;
  width: 260px;
  /* padding: 10px 8px; */
  max-height: 280px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /* opacity: 0; */
  /* pointer-events: none; */
}
.search-box li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  cursor: default;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  /* display: none; */
  overflow: auto;
}
.search-box li:hover {
  background: #efefef;
}
.search-btn {
  height: 38px;
  width: 38px;
  line-height: 38px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: black;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border: none;
  background: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.2/css/all.min.css">

<form class="d-flex ms-auto" action="/" method="post">
  <div class="search-box">
    <input
      class="form-control me-2 nav-search"
      autocomplete="off"
      name="search"
      placeholder="Type to Search..."
    />
    <div class="autocom-box">
      <li>Avengers</li>
      <li>Avengers</li>
      <li>Avengers</li>
      <li>Avengers</li>
    </div>
    <button class="search-btn" type="submit">
      <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

(The black border is the nav bar itself, the red border is the search window)

Comment: Thankyou very much Jacob it worked :). Didn't know it was this easy.

Comment: Hi, if the answer worked you can mark it as accepted and upvote it to let others with the same question know that it works.

Comment: I accepted it but I can't upvote it as it's saying I need 15 reputation to do it. Sorry I'm a beginner. I'll definitely upvote it when I have 15 reputations.